# Centering issue with <p> tag

Tags: css, position, centering, paragraph

I have a `img` and a `p` inside of a `div`.

I am trying to center the `p` vertically. I have tried `line-height` and a few other things.

Here is what it looks like

[image]

I would like "cute firefox prank" to be centered vertically relative to the `img`

**CSS**

```
img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

li p{
    display: inline;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin:0;
}
```

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/hA9N2/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done.**

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bWFa/)

All you have to do is add `vertical-align:middle;` to the `img`.

```
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: thanks i had tried `vertical-align:center;` which didnt work.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight It's always the little things.

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to your `img` rules. See http://jsfiddle.net/hA9N2/4/ for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why `p` has been set to `inline`; however, since `img` is an inline tag, you can use `vertical-align` to align it against other `inline` content.

I went ahead and made `p` a `block` element again, put the image inside it, and made the image vertically aligned.

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hA9N2/2/)

If you want to keep the `p` `inline`, then all you really need to do is set the image to be vertically aligned since `p` is set to `inline` as well.

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hA9N2/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
http://jsfiddle.net/gBNFK/1/

```
 li p{
        /* Add this */
        line-height: 42px;
        display: inline-table;
        vertical-align: top;
        /* Add this */
        color: black;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin:0;
    }
```